# Grand total and % total

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am currently using SQL Server 2008R2.

I would like to create a script that shows, per month, a grand total plus a % value of the items that come through in the name field.

This is the script I am currently using:

```
SELECT
 a.name, 
 DATENAME(M, a.Date) as Month,
 DATENAME(YEAR,a.Date) as Year,
 DATEPART(YYYY, a.Date) as YearNum,
 DATEPART (M, a.Date) as MonthNum,
 COUNT(*)  as [Total]

 FROM Database1.Table1 as a
 WHERE a.name = 'active'

 GROUP BY a.name, DATENAME(month, a.Date), 
 DATENAME(year, a.Date), DATEPART(YYYY, a.date), DATEPART (M, a.date)
 ORDER BY Month desc;
```

Is it possible, in the select statement above, to create a monthly total for all products (a.name)? At the moment, the above script gives a total per name, e.g. 
Television 25
Radio         25

In addition, it would be good to also see a % total as well, per name item, so for example Television 50%

Any help much appreciated – thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at ROLLUP() and CUBE()?

Answer (score 0):

Used CTE to solve the problem.